# Play war command not working

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

When I type `play war` or `play war blah -o blah.war --zip` I get this error

```
[error] Not a valid command: war (similar: start, run)
[error] Not a valid project ID: war
[error] Not a valid configuration: war
[error] Not a valid key: war (similar: watch, run, target)
[error] war
[error]    ^
```

I've been trying to google it but I have had no luck. When I run play everything works fine on my localhost and I'm am trying to get it deployed onto my ubuntu server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the error you show it seems you are using Play 2.0. Play 2.0 doesn't support WAR packaging (yet), that's only for Play 1.2.4 at the moment.

Comment: And it exists an experimental module for Play 2.0: https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin

Comment: Ok so if they don't support that than what would you suggest is the best way to deploy my application on my Ubuntu server? I have play installed on it and I can run `play start` which will then listen on port 9000 but in the browser all I get is `connection was reset by host`

Comment: @locrizak follow the oficial guide on deployment (https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Production) and add a nginx reverse proxy in front of Play

Comment: @Pere is there anyway to do it through Apache? I've been in their docs for a while now and I can't figure out the missing part. If everything is `ok` than the connection aborts and I get the `connection was reset by host`. If there is an error I see the Play stack trace page

Comment: you can't deploy Play inside Apache, you have to use Apache as a proxy that redirects the requests to Play. I've never done it myself, but there must be many manuals on how to use Apache as a proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your help I'll run with that for a while

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your play application as standalone java application without making its war file. Play framework has Netty NIO Server and that is embedded in a distribution file which you will need to generate by following these steps:

```
1. Navigate to project folder
2. type "play"
3. type "dist"
```

This will generate project snapshot zip file in dist folder of your play application.

Extract zip file in some folder. There you will find a start shell script file. Just execute that script file

Note: To make file executable type: chmod 777 start

./start

This will publish application and opens port to receive http request on default port 9000. If you want to change port when executing file,

./start -Dhttp.port=8080

This will publish application on port 8080